# custom NSView drawing not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to write a custom NSView that supports adding a background colour. I override drawRect

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {

    [[NSColor blackColor] set];  
    //[NSBezierPath fillRect:rect]; //I tried this too  
    NSRectFill([self bounds]);
```

}

And I set my custom view type to replace the content view NSView of my main window. But when I run it, the background does not turn black as expected - but some contained subviews do.

What I am doing wrong? My draw method is definitely getting called, but background does not change.

Comment: 1 - How are you replacing the content view with your custom view? 2 - How do you know your custom view's -drawRect: is being called?

Comment: There's a good chance your method is not being called. Try putting a breakpoint in your -drawRect: method and see if it is hit. if not, recheck your UI setup (code or nib) to see why your class is not being used.

Answer (score 0):

Do not replace the content view of your window as it is treated specially. Add your custom view to the content view, and set the autoresize flags instead.

Comment: That's incorrect: the content view is just a view and is no more special than any other. You can easily replace a content view by creating (and properly setting the frame and autosizing behavior) and replacing via NSWindow's -setContentView: or by clicking the content view in the window (in the nib/xib) and setting the class name to that of your custom view. Works just fine and is done quite regularly.

Comment: You are right. What I meant by specially, is that you cannot define its frame or its auto-resizing flags.

Comment: Actually, there's one "special" difference: if you use the content view instead of a custom view, initWithCoder will be called instead of initWithFrame.